# ANTD rowSelection won't check in the UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am trying to create a table with the ability to select.
I am able to display in the console a selection but it does not check the box anymore.
How did I lose the UI ability?

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Table } from "antd";

const App = ({ data, ...props }) => {
  const spreadArguments = (...args) => console.log(args);
  const rowSelection = {
    selectedRowKeys: [],
    onSelect: spreadArguments,
    onChange: spreadArguments
  };

  const columns = [
    {
      title: "Name",
      dataIndex: "name"
    },
    {
      title: "Age",
      dataIndex: "age"
    },
    {
      title: "Address",
      dataIndex: "address"
    }
  ];

  return (
    <>
      <Table dataSource={data} columns={columns} rowSelection={rowSelection} />
    </>
  );
};

const data = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 46; i++) {
  data.push({
    key: i,
    name: `Edward King ${i}`,
    age: 32,
    address: `London, Park Lane no. ${i}`
  });
}

ReactDOM.render(<App data={data} />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the UI didn't update is because in `rowSelection` you always pass `selectedRowKeys: []` an empty array. So state never updates.

Try the following snippet:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Table } from "antd";

const App = ({ data, ...props }) => {
  const [selectedRowKeys, setSelectedRowKeys] = React.useState([]);

  const spreadArguments = (selectedRowKeys) => {
    setSelectedRowKeys(selectedRowKeys);
    console.log(selectedRowKeys);
  };
  const rowSelection = {
    selectedRowKeys,
    onSelect: spreadArguments,
    onChange: spreadArguments
  };

  const columns = [
    {
      title: "Name",
      dataIndex: "name"
    },
    {
      title: "Age",
      dataIndex: "age"
    },
    {
      title: "Address",
      dataIndex: "address"
    }
  ];

  return (
    <Table dataSource={data} columns={columns} rowSelection={rowSelection} />
  );
};

const data = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 46; i++) {
  data.push({
    key: i,
    name: `Edward King ${i}`,
    age: 32,
    address: `London, Park Lane no. ${i}`
  });
}

ReactDOM.render(<App data={data} />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason in your example is that you do not pass `data` in `App`.

If you create this array inside your `App` function you could use it

```
const App = ({ ...props }) => {
  const spreadArguments = (...args) => console.log(args);
  const rowSelection = {
    selectedRowKeys: [],
    onSelect: spreadArguments,
    onChange: spreadArguments
  };

  const data = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 46; i++) {
    data.push({
      key: i,
      name: `Edward King ${i}`,
      age: 32,
      address: `London, Park Lane no. ${i}`
    });
  }


  const columns = [
    {
      title: "Name",
      dataIndex: "name"
    },
    {
      title: "Age",
      dataIndex: "age"
    },
    {
      title: "Address",
      dataIndex: "address"
    }
  ];

  return (
    <>
      <Table dataSource={data} columns={columns} rowSelection={rowSelection} />
    </>
  );
};


ReactDOM.render(<App data={data} />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

You can also leave almost everything in your example as it is, nut remove `data` from `App props

```
const App = ({ ...props }) => {
```

I imagine that data might be passed as props from parent component. If it is than parent component should use `App` this way:

```
const Parent = () => {
    const data = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 46; i++) {
        data.push({
          key: i,
          name: `Edward King ${i}`,
          age: 32,
          address: `London, Park Lane no. ${i}`
        });
    }

    return(
      <App data={data}/>
    )
}
```